# Analogue of R's simulate function in Julia?

Tags: r, julia, glm

I'm trying to use Julia's GLM package. Based on my experience in R, I have always loved its `simulate` function

```
simulate(object, nsim = 1, seed = NULL, ...)
```

which draws response from a fitted model. Is there any method similar in Julia that can apply to its fitted GLM model?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such function, but it should be relatively easy to implement it for your special case.

Here is an example for unweighted OLS with Gaussian (family `Normal()`) assumption:

```
function simulate(m, n=1)
    predict(m) .+ randn(Int(nobs(m)), n)*sqrt(deviance(m)/dof_residual(m))
end
```

which is equivalent to R implementation.

As a side note: in my experience instead from the distribution used by `simulate` in R usually *mean response* or *predicted response* distributions are more useful depending on what you need.

**EDIT:**

Probably a more Julian way to do it would be to avoid generating the sample but to return an object that you can sample from like this:

```
simdist(m) = Normal.(predict(m), sqrt(deviance(m)/dof_residual(m)))
```

now you can use `rand` to perform sampling eg.:

```
sdm = simdist(m)
rand.(sdm)
rand.(sdm, 10)
```

This way you often can avoid allocation of large memory chunks. E.g. if you wanted `nobs=10^9` in R you would most probably run out of memory and using `simdist` you can efficiently generate what you need on the go.